# Unable to download file from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, boto3

I posted my code below.

Starting at line 84 is where I am having difficulty in coding. I cannot figure out why it will not allow me to download the PNG in the bucket. I have set the permissions in the public to full public access.

The most recent error I got was:

"A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden"

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
import logging
import boto3
import pprint
import math
import os
import botocore
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def mainMenu(): 
    print("1. Are you looking for a coach? Here is their contact data.")
    print("2. Are you a beginner? Select 2 for your exersises.")
    print("3. Are you some where in the middle of your journey? Select 3 for your exersises.")
    print("4. Are you more Advanced? Select 4 for your exersises.")
    print("5. Are you hardcore and love to workout? Select 5.")
    print("6. Look at progress photos here!")
    print("7. Quit")   

    selection=int(input("Lets lose weight together!!! Please Select a Number:"))
    if selection==1: 
       coach()
    elif selection==2:
         beginner()
    elif selection==3: 
        intermediate()
    elif selection==4: 
       advanced()
    elif selection==5: 
        hardcore()
    elif selection==6: 
        progress_Photos()
    elif selection==7: 
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Enter 1-7")
        while selection == 7:
            break

    selection=int(input("Lets lose weight together!!! Please Select a Number:"))
"""Selection number 1 Input user data into DynamoDB database """
def coach():
       dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
       table = dynamodb.Table('coachdata')
       response = table.scan()
       pprint.pprint(response, depth=3, compact = True)

"""Selection number 2 Calculate exersises for beginners """     
def beginner():
    poundsToLose = input("How many beginner pounds would you like to lose this month? ")
    poundsToLose = int(poundsToLose)
    pushupexersises = (poundsToLose * 2)
    situpexersises = (poundsToLose * 10)
    plankexersises = (poundsToLose * 5)
    print ("To lose {} pound this month do {} pushups {} situps and {} planks every day.".format(poundsToLose,pushupexersises,situpexersises,plankexersises))

"""Selection number 3 Calculate exersises for intermediate users"""      
def intermediate():
    poundsToLose = input("How many intermediate pounds would you like to lose this month? ")
    poundsToLose = int(poundsToLose)
    pushupexersises = (poundsToLose * 5)
    situpexersises = (poundsToLose * 15)
    plankexersises = (poundsToLose * 10)
    print ("To lose {} pound this month do {} pushups {} situps and {} planks every day.".format(poundsToLose,pushupexersises,situpexersises,plankexersises))

"""Selection number 4 Calculate exersises for advanced users"""
def advanced():
    poundsToLose = input("How many advanced pounds would you like to lose this month? ")
    poundsToLose = int(poundsToLose)
    pushupexersises = (poundsToLose * 10)
    situpexersises = (poundsToLose * 20)
    plankexersises = (poundsToLose * 15)
    print ("To lose {} pound this month do {} pushups {} situps and {} planks every day.".format(poundsToLose,pushupexersises,situpexersises,plankexersises))

"""Selection number 5 Calculate exersises for hardcore users"""   
def hardcore():
    poundsToLose = input("How many HARDCORE pounds would you like to lose this month? ")
    poundsToLose = int(poundsToLose)
    pushupexersises = (poundsToLose * 20)
    situpexersises = (poundsToLose * 40)
    plankexersises = (poundsToLose * 30)
    print ("To lose {} pound this month do {} pushups {} situps and {} planks every day.".format(poundsToLose,pushupexersises,situpexersises,plankexersises))


"""Selection number upload progress photos to S3 """     
def progress_Photos():
    """Retrieve an object from an Amazon S3 bucket

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :return: botocore.response.StreamingBody object. If error, return None.
    """

    # Retrieve the object
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket='edu.umuc.sdev400.rharner.letsworkout', Key='beforeandafter.PNG' )
    except ClientError as e:
        # AllAccessDisabled error == bucket or object not found
        logging.error(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainMenu()
```

Comment: What about bucket policies?

Comment: If I run your code (`response = s3.get_object(Bucket='edu.umuc.sdev400.rharner.letsworkout', Key='beforeandafter.PNG' )`, it successfully returns the object. If it is not working for you, then please edit your question to show the permissions assigned to the credentials being used by this program. (Is it on an EC2 instance? Then show the permissions of the associated role. If it is using credentials from an IAM User, show the permissions on the user.) Even if an object is public, the IAM User/Role still needs permission to use Amazon S3.